# How to have the variable evaluated in dict function?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is what I have

```
TEST_KEY = "test_key"

def get_dict():
   return dict(TEST_KEY = "test_value")

print(get_dict())
```

This will print out `{'TEST_KEY': 'test_value'}`

but I want it evaluate to `{'test_key': 'test_value'}`

Is there a way to achieve this, to have python not evaluate TEST_KEY inside the dict function as a literal String but instead as the variable defined earlier?

Comment: Use [dictionary display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-dict_display) instead of [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-keyword-argument): `{TEST_KEY: "test_value"}`

Comment: "to have python not evaluate TEST_KEY inside the dict function as a literal String but instead as the variable defined earlier?" It's not "inside" the function, and it's not being evaluated as a string. It is being *used as the name of* a *keyword argument* to the function. This is a matter of Python's function-calling syntax; we can't change how that works, but we can just *not use a function call* - the natural way to create a dict is with the display (also called literal) syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close! But the way you're assigning the key and value is not quite right.

Try changing `dict` to `{}` and `=` to `:` like below. This will use the variable value as the key.

```
TEST_KEY = "test_key"

def get_dict():
   return {TEST_KEY: "test_value"}

print(get_dict())
```